# Pyqt5 Frameless window to a parent and child

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

first time using stackoverflow. I'll try to write my question as clear as posible.

1. I'm creating a First Window parent of a Second Window(the child one).
2. When I click in a button from the First Window I want to open the Second Window.
3. In the Window I send back some text to the First Window using .parent() method
4. I want both windows to be frameless using self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

My code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QLineEdit, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRect
import sys

class FirstWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(FirstWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.setFixedSize(400,400)

        self.go_to_second_window = SecondWindow(self)

        ######################################################

        self.button_go_second_window = QPushButton(self)

        self.button_go_second_window.setGeometry(QRect(40,150,220,50))
        self.button_go_second_window.setStyleSheet("QPushButton { background-color: rgba(63, 142, 191, 255); color : rgba(242, 242, 242, 255) }")

        self.button_go_second_window.clicked.connect(self.go_second_window)  

        ###################################################### 

        self.show()

    def go_second_window (self):

        self.go_to_second_window.show()


class SecondWindow(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        super(SecondWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        #self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.setFixedSize(400,400)

        ######################################################
        self.field = QLineEdit(self)
        self.field.move(40,100)
        ######################################################

        self.button_send_data_back = QPushButton(self)
        self.button_send_data_back.setText("Send")
        self.button_send_data_back.setGeometry(QRect(40,150,220,50))
        self.button_send_data_back.setStyleSheet("QPushButton { background-color: rgba(63, 142, 191, 255); color : rgba(242, 242, 242, 255) }")

        self.button_send_data_back.clicked.connect(self.send_data_back)  



    def send_data_back (self):

        go_to_first_window = FirstWindow(self)
        self.parent().button_go_second_window.setText(self.field.text())
        self.field.setText("")

        go_to_first_window.show() 

        self.close()


if __name__ == "__main__" :
    App = QApplication (sys.argv)
    window = FirstWindow()
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

My problem:

This works exactly as I expect. The problem is that the second window is not frameless.

If i uncomment  `#self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)` in the Second Window init it wont work as I expect.

If I uncomment it and set `super(SecondWindow, self).__init__(parent)` to `super(SecondWindow, self).__init__(parent=None)` I will have the two windows frameless and working as I expect but I won't be able to send my data back to the First Window since .parent() method won't find a parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use parent() to get the object from the other window? I point this out because you are forcing the second window to be a child of the second window, and that has secondary consequences like the one you see.

On the other hand, every time you do `go_to_first_window = FirstWindow(self)` you are creating a new window so in some tests you can have a lot of hidden windows that consume memory unnecessarily.

In general in Qt signals should be used to send information to other elements.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QLineEdit, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRect, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
import sys


class FirstWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(FirstWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setFixedSize(400, 400)

        self.second_window = SecondWindow()

        self.button_go_second_window = QPushButton(self)
        self.button_go_second_window.setGeometry(QRect(40, 150, 220, 50))
        self.button_go_second_window.setStyleSheet(
            "QPushButton { background-color: rgba(63, 142, 191, 255); color : rgba(242, 242, 242, 255) }"
        )

        self.button_go_second_window.clicked.connect(self.go_second_window)
        self.second_window.sendDataSignal.connect(self.receive_data_slot)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def go_second_window(self):
        self.second_window.show()

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def receive_data_slot(self, text):
        self.button_go_second_window.setText(text)


class SecondWindow(QDialog):
    sendDataSignal = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(SecondWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setFixedSize(400, 400)

        self.field = QLineEdit(self)
        self.field.move(40, 100)
        self.button_send_data_back = QPushButton(self)
        self.button_send_data_back.setText("Send")
        self.button_send_data_back.setGeometry(QRect(40, 150, 220, 50))
        self.button_send_data_back.setStyleSheet(
            "QPushButton { background-color: rgba(63, 142, 191, 255); color : rgba(242, 242, 242, 255) }"
        )
        self.button_send_data_back.clicked.connect(self.send_data_back)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def send_data_back(self):
        self.sendDataSignal.emit(self.field.text())
        self.field.clear()
        self.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = FirstWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to pyqt5, most of the things I write in my code come from tutorials. So I think there are some concepts in pyqt5 that I don't fully understand. 
Thank you for your answer. It helps me clarify how to interact between windows and send data.
Have a nice day